# Block X-Frame Firefox => How to enable on Html5?

Tags: html, ajax, xml, jsp

```
    <!-- TELA -->
    <td colspan="3">
<iframe src="radio.html" width="800" marginwidth="0" height="450" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="0">
    </iframe>
```

How to enable the X-frame on firefox Html5 ?

Comment: are you having an issue that your website is not displaying in iframe?

Comment: The Firefox has displayed this advice one or twice times, but we dont what is this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several options

1) you can add this `meta` tag in your `head` tag, most chances that it won't work!

```
  <meta name="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="ALLOW-FROM" />
```

2) You can bypass `X-Frame-Options` in an `<iframe>`using [X-Frame-Bypass](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass) Web Component.

3) You can use this [Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ignore-x-frame-options-header/) of `firefox` for ignoring the X-FRAME